# pdo_sqlsrv ext installed but sqlsrv_connect() function not running

Tags: pdo, sqlsrv

I'm using xampp with PHP 5.4.25 and have installed pdo_sqlsrv extension

**phpinfo():**

```
PHP Version 5.4.25
System  Windows NT BANG-PC 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Business Edition) i586
Build Date  Feb 5 2014 21:16:25
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86
```

[image]

**`php.ini`:**

`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`

I downloaded two versions of sqlsrv:

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

But just `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` worked.

When running this code:

```
$link = sqlsrv_connect($server, 'username', 'abc.123');
```

It shows error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Did I get the correct pdo_sqlsrv extension?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem: I missed the configuration of `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` in php.ini

So the final config is:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_connect()` is the function of `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`. Check online documentation for more (you also have an offline help file from driver package I guess): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296172(SQL.90).aspx